# Converting packed 64-bit integers to packed 8-bit integers with signed saturation using AVX512

Tags: c, intrinsics, avx, avx512

I am looking for a solution for saturating packed 64-bit integers to 8-bit integers. Looked at `_mm256_cvtepi64_epi8` but instead of saturating, it truncates which results in unwanted output.

My program is as below:

```
int main()
{
    __m256i a, b, c;
    __m128i d;

    a = _mm256_set1_epi64x(127);
    b = _mm256_set1_epi64x(1);
    c = _mm256_add_epi64x(a, b);
    d = _mm256_cvtepi64_epi8(c);
}
```

I expect the output (d) to contain four `127` (saturated), however the program yields four `-128` elements (truncated from `128`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_mm256_cvtepi64_epi8` is AVX512.  (Specifically AVX512VL; the 512-bit version is AVX512F).  You tagged that but your (original) title only said AVX.

Anyway, your options include doing saturated addition in the first place with `_mm256_adds_epi8` so you can have 8x as many elements per vector.

(And as discussed in comments, for 8x8 => 8-bit saturating multiply, you might just want in-lane unpack to feed `_mm256_mullo_epi16`, and pack pairs of results back down with in-lane `_mm256_packs_epi16` (`vpacksswb`).  Although sign-extending in-lane unpack is not convenient so you might consider `vpmovsx`.  Either way, you definitely don't need to widen more than 16-bit elements; `int16_t` can hold the full product of two `int8_t` without overflow.)

---

Or to do it the way you asked, AVX512 does have signed and unsigned saturation versions of the down-convert instructions, along with the truncation version you found. [`VPMOVQB`, `VPMOVSQB`, and `VPMOVUSQB`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovqb:vpmovsqb:vpmovusqb) are all documented together.

`__m128i _mm256_cvtsepi64_epi8(__m256i a);` does signed saturation.  It's available in a version with an `__m512i` source, and a version that stores to memory directly (optionally as a masked store).

(The store version is no more efficient on mainstream CPUs, but it did allow KNL / KNM (which lack AVX512BW) to do narrow byte-masked stores.)

---

**Do not widen your data to 64-bit elements unless you have to.  That's 1/8th of the work per vector compared to 8-bit elements, and 32x32 => 32-bit and 64x64 => 64-bit SIMD multiplies need 2 uops per instruction on Intel since Haswell.**

---

Another option is to pack 2 vectors -> 1 vector of the same width as the 2 inputs, but they only work in-lane pack instructions.  e.g. `_mm256_packs_epi16` as mentioned above.  They're only available for 2:1 element size ratios, not all the way from 64 or 32 to 8 in one step.  (So yet another reason to avoid widening too much).

But if you look at the total number of shuffles to produce N bytes of output data, it tends to come out slightly ahead.  e.g. for 4 input vectors, you need 2 + 1 shuffles instead of 4 to narrow from 32 to 8 bit.  (And maybe a 4th shuffle if you need to fix up in-lane, if you weren't able to feed them instructions with data interleaved odd/even in 128-bit lanes).  You have to look at the big picture of how many shuffles (or potentially other instructions like AND or AVX512 byte-masking) it takes to unpack as well as re-pack.

2:1 packing has the advantage of leading to wider stores if you're even storing the results.  If not then that's an even bigger advantage over the new AVX512 1->1 vector narrowing instructions, where you'd need shuffles to recombine them into a 256-bit vector.

Comment: @thnghh: there are 16-bit and 32-bit multiply instructions.  If your inputs are narrow enough, you could maybe use that instead of widening to 64 and saturating back down to 8. There's even [`vpmaddubsw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddubsw) which does horizontal accumulation; you could use that after odd/even masking of one input, or some kind of in-lane unpack to feed [`vpacksswb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/packsswb:packssdw) back down to byte. SIMD rule of thumb: widen as little as necessary to keep your data density high. (Vectors with little entropy are usually a bad sign)

Comment: The first solution is quite good for the addition case (a+b). However, sometimes I have to solve the multiplication case (a*b). For example:

**a** contains eight `50`,
**b** contains eight `40`,
`c = _mm256_mul_epi32(a, b)` yields four `200`,

I want **d** to contain four `127` (saturated version of **c**)

Comment: @thnghh: In that example case, you only need 16-bit inputs to feed `vpmullw` -> `vpacksswb`.  (**Traditional 2:1 saturating pack instructions are in-lane, but you only need 1 per 2 vectors, instead of 1 per vector with the AVX512 shuffles.  Use whem when possible.**)

Comment: Actually I want to multiply packed 8-bit signed integers, then saturate to 8-bit packed result. However, I can only find `_mm512_mul_epi32` function, which multiplies packed 32-bit signed integers to produce packed 64-bit result. Therefore, I have to convert packed 8-bit to packed 32-bit, multiply using the function `_mm512_mul_epi32`, get result in 64-bit and come up to the problem above.

Comment: @thnghh: Did you miss my last comment?  `vpmullw` is 16x16 => 16-bit multiply so you only need to widen your inputs that much, not to 32-bit!  Or my first comment mentioned a way to use `vpmaddubsw` as an 8x8 => 16-bit widening multiply (but only if you can treat one input as signed and the other as unsigned).  You can search for instruction mnemonics in [Intel's intrisincs finder](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,AVX_512,Other&text=vpmullw)

Comment: I don't understand whether I can use `vpmullw` directly, or I have to use 1 of 8 listed intrinsics in [Intel's intrinsics finder](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,AVX_512,Other&text=vpmullw). Sorry I am new to this field.

Comment: @thnghh: you always want to use intrinsics, not inline asm.  It's just easier to remember and type the asm mnemonics than `_mm512_mullo_epi16` or whatever it is, as a way to talk about which hardware operations we want to make the CPU do.  (And what asm we want the compiler to emit.)  When you're optimizing SIMD code, the "programming model" is what the hardware can do efficiently.  You target that indirectly via C or C++ by writing code that can compile to the efficient asm you have in mind.  (At least that's how *I* think about it, because I do know the asm and CPU performance details.)

Comment: my question is solved, but can I ask whether there is a website that list the asm mnemonics and corresponding meanings so that I can search faster next time?

Comment: @thnghh: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ is an extract from Intel's vol.2 PDF manual.  But really Intel's intrinsics finder is pretty good, if you know the terminology Intel uses to describe things.  Or to search asm mnemonics, you can always just put those into the intrinsics finder as the search term and get an intrinsic docs (not always as detailed as the asm manual).  The intrinsics finder gets pretty bloated with all the masked versions of AVX512 instructions.  Consider unchecking the AVX512 box, or maybe just the AVX512VL box, before searching